# Makefile: use multiple components on the right, processed in a same directory by macro $^

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with a line contains a list of components on the right side. I want to use macro $^ in order to archive the list which are in a different directory. The following line just use the first component in other directory and the rest processed in the current directory which is wrong:

```
libExApp.a: xapp_e.o xsage_e.o users.o id.o prog.o
    ar rc $@ ia32/$^
```

If I use curly bracket {}, then there is no comma between files to be processed in the same directory.

So, how can I use multiple components all processed in a same directory.

Comment: You should list the files you use as dependencies and just use `ar rc $@ $^` as the recipe. Also, consider dropping the attempt to use recipes that create files in one directory from files in another; `make` wasn't really designed with that in mind, and although it can be done, I prefer to just go with the traditional way of doing things, which is to create all files in place and use an `install` target to copy them to their destinations.

Comment: @reinierpost make can *absolutely* handle targets and prerequisites in arbitrary directories. Though certainly some parts of that can get more complicated. That's not, at all, the same thing about building targets in *installed* locations though. That's not something that should be done.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: Sure it can, I'm just advising against it.

Comment: Right, but I don't see why. Nothing about that is against the make design in any way. There are just corners that you need to be more careful with that way (and in fact make is *explicitly* set up to support this sort of thing in many places). The time when it *doesn't* make sense is when you try to build things "in place" where that means in installed locations. That, despite being handy for certain things, does have issues. Though those are mostly not make's fault.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just overly cautious. I use pattern rules where I can and I've been bitten by [their exact semantics in the presence of directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) but no doubt there are tidy ways to work with files across different directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. Do it right. Tell make where the *actual* prerequisites are and then just use `$^` normally.

```
libExApp.a: ia32/xapp_e.o ia32/xsage_e.o ia32/users.o ia32/id.o ia32/prog.o
        ar rc $@ $^
```

Or, to avoid repeating the `ia32` prefix you can use the `addprefix` function.

```
libExApp.a: $(addprefix ia32/,xapp_e.o xsage_e.o users.o id.o prog.o)
        ar rc $@ $^
```

Comment: The second option is good and short, but the only problem is that it modifies the target names i.e xapp_e.o xsage_e.o users.o id.o prog.o. I have many similar lines, and don't want to change the target names. Is there any way to modify the macro $^ ?

Comment: You *can* use `$(addprefix)` on `$^` in the recipe as well but you *should not* as it *will* confuse make and things will **not** work correctly. For example, by doing that you are telling make to *build* the `xapp_e.o`, etc. objects in the current directory (and use those for freshness checking of `libExApp.a`) but then to *actually* link the *copies* of those files from the `ia32` directory which may or may not be at all related. That is, you are **explicitly** breaking the operation mechanisms of make. So again, don't do it.